# How to center [image + text] of unknown width?

Tags: html, css

This is the header of my page:

```
--------------------------------
 Logo  | fixed  | Title with    
 Image | margin | unknown width 
--------------------------------
```

I want to horizontally center the whole header in my page. Currently I set the logo image as the background image of a container and wrap the title in the container.

HTML is:

```
<header role="banner">
  <div class="logo">
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </div>
</header>
```

CSS is:

```
header[role="banner"] .logo{
  height: 76px;
  background: url(/images/logo.png) no-repeat;
}

.logo h1{
  line-height: 76px;
  text-indent: 96px;
}
```

Before you answer please notice that the hard parts of this problem are:

1. The width of title is unknown.
2. There is a logo image to the left of the title. Only centering the title is what I already know how to do but not what I want. Centering the image is just wrong — [logo + title] is to be centered, logo should not be centered in the header.

Comment: Try to avoid using Background images for anything other then a Background :: Images provide nice SEO on there own, and some good alt text can take it even farther :)

Comment: Expanding on @Burdock's comment: if you can put the image in a `header h1:before{content:url(...)}`, your troubles might go away...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if your HTML is the best way of having a logo and page title.  I'd personally go with an `<img>` for the logo.

You can use the `display: table` and `display: table` cell for centering without knowing the width.

Here's how I'd do it with the image for a logo:

HTML

```
<header role="banner">
    <div class="extra-container">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100x76" alt="Logo Image" />
      </div>
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
header[role="banner"] {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header[role="banner"] .extra-container {
  display: table-cell;
}

header[role="banner"] .logo {
  margin-right: 40px;
  float: left;
}

header[role="banner"] .logo img {
  display: block;
}

h1{
  line-height: 76px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/UhIqUXe/1/edit

Comment: Thanks. I'm also thinking whether table is the only way to go here.

Comment: CSS `display: table` I presume, not an actual `<table>`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `<div>` to be honest.  Make the background of the `<header>` your background image like this:

```
header[role="banner"] {
  background: url(/images/logo.png) center top no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 76px;
}
```

And to center your title put `text-align: center;`

Comment: Seems a bit strange to use the banner background image, pore SEO in my opinion.

Comment: wasnt looking at the text-drawing at the beginning but the code he put is inline with what i posted.  He doesn't have an `<img>` in his code and his title is inside of that div, meaning it's on top of the image.  I just happened to read the part of the question that was a negative conflict.  Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

The header will need to have a width specified in order for the margin trick to work. If you don't know the exact width you could use a percentage for the header tag.

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at this source [CSS-Trick](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/)

The best way should be set margin..

`margin:0px auto 0px auto;`

this will set margin of top and bottom to 0px and right and left to auto,

this will trick the wrapperDiv in center( the container of image or text)

Comment: This is not text only problem. Please read the question again.

Comment: Please consider explaining the **given** problem instead of **only** providing links to external sources.